# Is $h(x)$ $:=$ $-1^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \over {\lfloor x+1 \rfloor}$ Riemann- and Lebesgue-integrable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

> Given the function,
>
> $h: [0, \infty) \rightarrow \Bbb R$,
>
> $h(x)$ $:=$ $-1^{\lfloor x \rfloor} \over {\lfloor x+1 \rfloor}$,
>
> I would like to check whether it is Riemann- or Lebesgue-integrable and calculate the value of the integral.

My approach looks like this:

$h(x)$ looks like a step function when we only take a look at it on intervals that possess a form like $(x_{k-1}, x_k)$ with $k \in \Bbb N$ and $k-1 < x_{k-1} < x_k < k$. In that case, we can write it as

$h(x)$ $=$ $-1^n \over n+1$ $\forall x \in (x_{k-1}, x_k)$, $\ k \in \Bbb N$.

Since every step function is Riemann-integrable by definition, $h(x)$ is Riemann-integrable too. But this means that it has to be Lebesgue-integrable too, meaning that

$\int_0^{\infty} |h(x)| < \infty$.

But this is not the case here since integrating the function gives us $\log$$($$1 \over n+1$$) $, and putting in the values gives us that $\int_0^{\infty} |h(x)| = \infty$, which is not the desired result.

Were am I mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$h$ is not Riemann integrable** as Riemann integral exists only for functions defined on a closed bounded interval, which is not the case of $[0,\infty)$.

**$h$ is not either Lebesgue integrable** for the reason you noticed: $$\int_0^{\infty} |h(x)| \ dx =  \infty.$$ However, $h$ is measurable as any step function.

Comment: Ha, makes sense, thank you! :-)

Comment: It seems that the improper integral $\int_0^\infty h(x)\,dx$ does converge, though.